# "these are the list of" or "this is the list of"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I have an essay that goes something like this.

**This is the list of** items that I found on the internet

1. Catz
2. Java
3. PUBG
4. StarWars

But I feel that I'm pointing to a list of item**s**. So should it be "These are the list of items" ?

I got confusing opinions from my colleagues. Could someone point the right one?

Comment: Or `These are the items that I found on the internet:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list has many items, but they are gathered in only one list. The list is singular. Lists can be counted.

So:

> This is the list of items.

or

> These are the items; I've put them in a list.

If you had two lists, or more, you could say

> These are the list**s** of items.